# Как добавить поддомен в Jetty?

Tags: java, jetty

Установил программу xWiki. Запустил и пишет. 
Starting Jetty on port 8080, please wait...

В итоге xwiki открывается по адресу 
http://localhost:8080/
и по внешнему ip адресу и привязанному домену (допустим webonline.company.ru)

Как настроить веб сервер Jetty, чтобы 
он открывался по адресу?
xwiki.webonline.company.ru

Comment: а в DNS зоне все прописано?

Comment: У нас сервер в DMZ, DNS установлен в другом месте. Это именно в DNS прописывается?

Comment: Разрешением имён в ip занимается именно DNS.

Comment: Ок, Спасибо, поменяем в dns